# Flutter web run with google-chrome parameters

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

I develop flutter with Intellij IDEA .
after search on internet i found this parameters to disable `update popup` and `restore previous tabs popup` on google chrome .

```
google-chrome-stable --disable-session-crashed-bubble --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'
```

**I want to know :**
**1)** How to config Intellij IDEA to run flutter web application with this parameters ?
**2)** Any idea to change flutter configuration files to run google chrome with this parameters as default .

Comment: You can try passing these options to Chrome in Chrome settings in **Settings | Tools | Web Browsers and Preview** - the IDE will launch Chrome with these parameters once you start your run configuration.